# How to scale a Path in Android?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

In my custom view the user can draw some [**paths**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) and afterwards these paths are merged with a background bitmap and everthing is saved in a .JPG file.
 The question is: If I scale the bitmap by 2x, how can I do the same scaling for paths?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setScale(2f, 2f);
path.transform(matrix);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
path.transform(matrix)
```

use

```
path p = new path()

p.addPath(oldpathtobetransformed, matrix);
```

use P to draw

Comment: you have to write your reason